# How to support multiple versions of the same schema in Java validation?

Tags: java, validation, xsd, versioning

I'd like to think ahead and include versioning in an XMLSchema document. It seems that the advised approach in w3c is to keep the namespace the same and use the version attribute.

So far so sensible.

However, don't I need then to be able to switch the schema to use for validation based on the specified version? Does the Java 6 XML schema validation facilty include this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that many people advise keeping the namespace the same.  I do not doubt that that approach works for many people (including most who advise it), but I've never seen a really compelling argument that it's the only plausible or advisable practice.  (And in systems that assume there can only ever be one schema for a particular namespace, changing the namespace may be the only way you'll ever be able to version a vocabulary.)

You are right, too, that keep the namespace constant across versions may mean you want to maintain multiple schemas.  The last time I looked at its documentation, Xerces J seemed to make it fairly straightforward to do what you need:  a validation call essentially involved saying "here, take *this* document and *this* schema, and validate".

Some people avoid the need for multiple schemas by saying that each new version will expand the set of valid documents, so each version's schema can be used against documents created to conform to earlier versions of the schema.  (A further refinement:  decimal point releases must be backward compatible in that way, and only major releases can be backwards incompatible -- and if they are, they must use a new namespace.)